# Keep the same file in two places without 2x memory

Tags: windows-8, windows-explorer, shortcuts

Sometimes I want to be able to get to a file from two different places, like if two courses have some course material in common but I don't wanna copy it because that seems wasteful. A shortcut with absolute path is not ideal because I could move the whole thing, and a shortcut with relative path is not ideal because I could change the name of a folder or something.

What I'd like to do is basically copy-paste without taking up twice the space. Like, I could rename or move around either "file" and it'd still work, but they'd point to the same actual file. Not the biggest of deals but if that's possible it'd be neat.

I'm on windows 8.1.

Comment: I think "Hardlink" suits what you wanted (I don't have any personal experience trying it but give it a try and see how you go). I saw some details instruction (and explanation) here http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/

Comment: You would have to have a folder of original files.  Then you could make 2 or more hardlink, with the **mklink** command and you could move or rename the hardlink, but I believe the original has to stay put.

Comment: The original does **not** have to stay put--with a hardlink, **there _is_ no original!** The two files are completely identical, each is a file in its own right. You can even delete either of them and the other will remain unaffected. (As far as I know, please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Comment: @seaturtle I tested it and you're right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No one has posted this as an answer yet, so I'll go ahead: use hard links. In cmd, if you want to copy `C:\somePath\someBook.pdf`, this yields the hard link `someBookCopy.pdf` in the current folder.

`mklink /H someBookCopy.pdf C:\somePath\someBook.pdf`

Details: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/16226/complete-guide-to-symbolic-links-symlinks-on-windows-or-linux/